# vimeo embed using cfmediaplayer

Tags: video, coldfusion, media-player, mp4, vimeo

Using Coldfusion 9's `cfmediaplayer` tag, I was able to get a video from vimeo to play in the coldfusion media player. I wanted to get around the iframe that vimeo serves as embed method and use the coldfusion player.
I used the following code (with videos I got from [this page](http://hwdmediashare.co.uk/forum/27-development-customisation/53527-vimeo-pro)):

```
<cfmediaplayer name="myVid" source="http://player.vimeo.com/external/35713812.sd.mp4?s=127f879fc781ae7e62049696679e5615"" />
```

And it worked perfectly.

Then I upgraded my Coldfusion to CF10. Adobe had upgraded their cfmediaplayer to support flash and html5 videos. But when I tried with the same code as above, the media player would tell me that the service is unavailable or the type is unsupported.
Vimeo serves mp4 files, if I'm not mistaken (at least the ones in the link are).
I also retested in Coldfusion 9 on another computer, where the code snippet is still working properly.

Does anybody have any idea what is going on?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it was a temporary network issue. I just tried your code (removing the double quote at the end) and the video loaded. If you still see the issue, maybe share what browser you are using.